# Ubuntu 18.04, two monitors. When one turns off, they don't "reset" to a single monitor. I can still move my mouse on to the turned-off monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, monitor

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I have two monitors, one hooked up to an HDMI port, the other to displayport.

My left monitor is labeled 1, and primary. My right monitor is labeled 2.

Previously, when I'd turn the 1 monitor off, the 2 monitor would flicker, and reset itself as primary. At this point, the mouse pointer was contained on the monitor. Now, out of nowhere, when I turn it off, the mouse pointer will still go off screen to monitor 1.

I have no clue what the problem could be. Does anyone have advice?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and clarify which monitor is which? Is the left/primary monitor HDMI or DP? Likewise for right/number 2.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon which one is connected to DisplayPort and which one to HDMI.

- Turning of the DP one will force the rearrangement of your windows.
- Turning of the HDMI one will not.

This is a DisplayPort "feature".